# TernRename creates a new split in vim

Tags: javascript, vim, vim-plugin, tern

I'm using [tern_for_vim](https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim) and trying to rename a variable. When I run `:TernRename` I get asked for the new name of the variable. After I provide that and press Enter, the variable gets renamed and then I get a new split with all the references where the variable was found. How can I get rid of that? It's annoying to have to close that after each rename...

Comment: Read the plugin's documentation and use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: Their documentation is basically the `README` which I already read and I usually only use the issue tracker to report a issue (bug/problem) not to ask questions about how to use the plugin when there's no documentation... Isn't that what SO is for? So experienced users can give answers when there's no documentation? :)

Comment: First, that plugin has documentation (lightweight but still). Second, the option you "found in a closed PR" happens to be [documented](https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim/blob/master/doc/tern.txt#L171). Third, SO is not a support desk.

Comment: Thank you for your acid but accurate comment. I did not know to check the `doc` folder... Looks like lack of knowledge is a capital offence in the IT industry and people are getting worked up about it. And sorry for miss-using Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has this problem, I did a little digging and I found a [closed PR](https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim/pull/155) that allows you to change the default behavior.

So, adding this to your `.vimrc` will disable the 'show-location-after-rename' behavior:

`let g:tern_show_loc_after_rename=0`

**EDIT**: Looks like this is documented [here](https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim/blob/master/doc/tern.txt#L171) as @romainil mentioned.